# How to upload youtube videos via gdata.youtube python library in Django

Tags: python, django, youtube, youtube-api

I have a python/django powered app which has a feature that I can post videos to youtube by using the gdata.youtube python library

My reference is as follows: https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python

The former developer followed the instructions found in this very useful page such as fulfilling the requirements and authentication to upload videos. But it does not work.
When I run firebug, there is a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR and it traces to upload_prepare
function in my view, which most likely is in the save part.

```
    def upload_prepare(request):
        if request.POST:
            form = UploadForm(request.user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                #error is in the next line
                video = form.save()
```

He also followed the instructions on how to post a youtube video via Browserupload

My code are as follows:

models.py

```
    class Category(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        scheme = models.URLField()

        def toGData(self):
            return gdata.media.Category(
                text=self.text,
                label=self.label,
                scheme=self.scheme)

    class YoutubeUser(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        ...

        #Initialize gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService object
        def yt_service(self):
            try:
                return selt._yt_service
            except AttributeError:
        #setting up developer key and client ID
                yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
                yt_service.developer_key = settings.SYNCR_YT_DEVKEY
                yt_service.client_id = 'LOLtest'
        #setting up a authentication token
                if self.token:
                    yt_service.SetAuthSubToken(self.token)
                self._yt_service = yt_service
                return yt_service

        #Setting up AuthSub authentication for web apps
        def authsub_url(self, request):
        #urls.py url
            base = reverse('authlanding', args=(self.id,))
            next = 'http://%s%s?next=%s' % (request.get_host(), base, urllib2.quote(request.build_absolute_uri()))
            scope = 'http://gdata.youtube.com'
            secure = False
            session = True

            return self.yt_service.GenerateAuthSubUrl(next, scope, secure, session)

        #upgrade to a session token
        def upgrade_to_session(self):
            yt_service = self.yt_service
            yt_service.SetAuthSubToken(self.token)
            yt_service.UpgradeToSessionToken()
            self.token = yt_service.current_token.get_token_string()
            self.save()
```

So far those where the codes in my models.py, here are the codes in my forms.py, the save function that caused the error is found here (look in the upload_prepare view above)

forms.py

```
    class UploadForm(forms.Form):
        video_title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        ...
        #https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python#UploadingVideos
        #Browser-based upload
        def save(self):
            mediagroup = gdata.media.Group(
                title=gdata.media.Title(text=self.cleaned_data['video_title']),
                description=gdata.media.Description(description_type="plain", text=self.cleaned_data['video_description']),
                keywords=gdata.media.Keywords(text=self.cleaned_data['tags']),
        #category already in GData format look in models.py
                category=self.cleaned_data['category'].toGData(),
                player=None,
            )
            video_entry = gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry(media=mediagroup)
            response = self.yt_user.yt_service.GetFormUploadToken(video_entry)
            post_url = response[0]
            youtube_token = response[1]

            video = Video.objects.create(
                author=self.yt_user,
                post_url=post_url,
                youtube_token=youtube_token,
                title=self.cleaned_data['video_title'],
                description=self.cleaned_data['video_description'],
                tag_list=self.cleaned_data['tags'],
            )
            self.video = video
            return video
```

The form used in the html to pass the data in the other hand combines django forms, django custom tagging and ajax

forms.py

```
    class UploadForm(forms.Form):
        video_title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        video_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 60,
                                             'rows': 10}))
        category = forms.ModelChoiceField(Category.objects, empty_label=None)
        tags     = TagField(
               label=_('tags (comma separated)'),
               required=True,
               )
```

youtube_tags.py

```
    def youtube_upload_form(context):
    #UploadForm from above
        upload_form = UploadForm(context['user'])
        context['upload_form'] = upload_form
        return context

    register.inclusion_tag('syncr/youtube/upload.html',
                   takes_context=True)(youtube_upload_form)
```

add_post.html

```
    <script>
        function upload_video_to_youtube(url){
            action = "%s?nexturl=%s" % (youtube_url, url)
            var new_form = create_element('form', {'method': 'post', 'action': action, 'enctype':"multipart/form-data"});
            $('#youtube_upload_form input').each(function(){
                var obj = this.cloneNode(true);
                new_form.appendChild(obj);
            });
            document.body.appendChild(new_form);
            new_form.submit();
        }
    </script>

    {% block body %}
    ...
    <div id="rd2-radioOptionContent" class="hide radioOptionContent">
    {% youtube_upload_form %}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Hope everyone gets a perfect picture of the codes I posted. If read clearly, most of the instructions posted on the reference where followed (although the form used to submit the data is slightly different) and given that I had a 500 Internal Server Error, I need to find the problem in these lines of codes. Any answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: where did you get 500? if gdata returns 500, its youtube's bug; if your own code, you should post the debug trace here

Comment: Oh my really? Its also one of my theories that its a youtube bug, but if it is, how should I get it working?

Comment: The debug traces to the function upload_prepare in the video.save so the error is most likely in the save in forms.py but I can't find the error

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the second line of your yt_service method, should be self not selt. Maybe that's the problem?